# Bundler including gem in ignored group

Tags: ruby, bundler

When I `Bundle.require(:default)` I'm getting an error saying that one of the gems in my test group isn't found. I installed this bundle `--without test` so this makes sense, but shouldn't all the gems in the `:test` group be ignored here? Isn't that the point?

Thoughts on what might be wrong with this environment?

**EDIT:**

It may have something to do with my setup for this projects. I'm caching the gems in `vendor/cache` with `bundle package --all`. My cache has gems from git, file, and traditional sources. Bundler is reporting

> some gems appear to be missing from your vendor/cache -> could not
>   find gem factory_girl which is required by

Answer (score 0):

try editing the gemfile so that it fg is like this:

```
group :development do
    gem 'factory_girl'
end
```

Then it won't look for it in the testing group. Or, I can't tell which group you actually want it in, but my point is limit it down to the group you want.

Also, try running `Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)` instead of just `(:default)`. That would put it back to the standard Rails requirements.

Finally, I figure you're trying to install the gems for development(or production?) have you tried running `bundle install --without test production` to make sure that nothing is coming in from the other group you aren't focused on?

Edit:
Last try before I'm out of ideas. From the documentation it seems like you can specify the load path as well as requiring them. Try setting Bundler.setup as well? I don't have a rails environment on this machine so I can't test.

```
Bundle.setup(:production)
Bundle.require(:production)
```

or

```
Bundle.setup(:production, :default)
Bundle.require(:production, :default)
```

Comment: By running `Bundle.require(:default)` bundler should only be looking at gems in the default group. Any other group, be it `testing` or `development`, shouldn't be in scope. I'm not sure how moving the gem from `testing` to `development` would fix the problem; I'd have to do this movement for all the `testing` gems which defeats the purpose of the groups to begin with. Nonetheless, I'll try moving everything into `development` to see if `testing` has some special meaning.

Comment: Can you copy over your gemfile?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Yes I'm installing for production. I've run bundler `--without test development`, so that's why the gems are missing (expected). My problem is I can't figure out why bundler is attempting to include them since I'm only requiring the `:default`.